# Can I reference a dynamically generated sitemap in robots.txt?

Tags: dynamic, sitemap, robots.txt

I'm setting up a sitemap for my website, and what I've done was creating an endpoint that generates the sitemap for it.

If I put the URL for my API on `robots.txt`, could the crawler bots access that and get the sitemap or will they not send an API request?

Comment: There is no difference between an "API request" and an ordinary HTTP request.

Comment: Is the sitemap generated on the server-side or on the client-side?

Comment: the sitemap is generated on the server-side